# Pelican stopped generating the site

Tags: python, blogs, pelican

Everything was working fine.

But now when I do `pelican content`, nothing happens. Literally. Command Line is just stuck.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `PAGE_PATHS` value in the settings file.

Turned out that it cannot be set to [""].

Changed it to `pages`

Comment: I think you should file a bug report -- the CLI should at least complain about the missing variable.

Comment: @Teyras, it is not missing, the default value is good enough. What I meant is that you cannot set it to `""`.

Comment: Ah, okay then. Yet, it would still be nice, if the CLI said what's wrong instead of leaving it for you to figure out :)

Comment: @Teyras, this is not the only thing I had to figure out myself. Pelican is nice anyways =)